# How to combine Web/Mobile user authentication

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

I'm using Java/Spring/Spring Security for my web project.
The API is available through REST, but each API call requires a user to be authenticated. Currently my authentication is username/password based, which works well for web users.
Next, I'm going to create mobile Apps to access the same functionality.

The API calls are preferably the same, but the authentication will probably be token-based. 
Should I consider mapping web/mobile HTTP requests to different controllers in order to authenticate differently?

What are the best practices here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The token based authentication is ideal when you have multiple environments such as mobile and classic web platform.
So you only need to implement a token based authentication which will be used by both platform without made any changes to your API.

Here an example of a token based authentication:
https://github.com/RedFroggy/angular-spring-hmac

Comment: Thanks a lot! I checked your GitHub project, and it seems it has all the information I need.
Which Spring Security book/document did you use to learn these security concepts and Spring configuration details?

Comment: i've used the official Spring Security and Spring documentation